# MongoDB query fails if not using the correct index

Tags: mongodb

Mongo collection is for Example:

```
{ 
  entityId: 43212
  jobExists: true,
  value: 75,
  ...
  parent: "Mogli"
}
{
  entityId: 12435
  jobExists: false,
  reasonForNonExistence: "Too many arguments",
  value: 97,
  ...
  parent: "Baba"
}
```

etc....

Notice that **only records that has jobExists:false contain also another field called reasonForNonExistence**, which other records dont have.
I have around 11 Million records in the DB.

Index exist on EntityId and jobExists fields.

When querying a very complex query, which first 2 conditions are "entityId:xxx" and "jobExists:false" , rest of the query checks conditions on the "reasonForNonExistence" field.

Most of the times the query succeeds and everything is ok, BUT, When mongo chooses NOT the use the index on entityId and jobExists, he actually tries to check the other conditions as well, leading to an undefined exception for the field reasonForNonExistence.

My question is, Why mongo is failing if he is not using the index, when it is clear that he should be even checking the rest of the conditions since the first 2 could filter the document out?

What can I do to avoid this scenario and make it work?
(I know about the option to check that field is defined within the query... Just wanted to see if there is a better way)

Thanks.

This is the query that is being created by our code, and which is run:

```
db.reports.find(
{"$and":
[
    {"$and":
    [
        {"jobExists":false},
        {"entityId":
            {"$in":["878"]}
        },
        {"$or":
        [
            {"entries":{"$exists":false}},
            {"entries":{"$size":0}},
            {"entries":{"$elemMatch":{"invoicedAt":{"$exists":false}}}},
            {"entries":{"$elemMatch":
            {"$and":
            [
                {"invoicedAt":{"$lte":{"$date":1529366400000}}},
                {"invoicedAt":{"$gte":{"$date":1483228800000}}}
            ]}
            }}
        ]},
        {"$or":
        [
            {"entries":{"$exists":false}},
            {"entries":{"$size":0}},
            {"entries":{"$elemMatch":{"country":{"$exists":false}}}},
            {"entries":{"$elemMatch":{"country":
            {"$in":["AT","BE","BG","HR","CY","CZ","DK","EE","FI","FR","DE","GR","HU","IE","IT","LV","LT","LU","MT","NL","PL","PT","RO","SK","SI","ES","SE","GB","NO","CH","RS"]}}}}
        ]}
    ]},
    {"$or":
    [
        {"companyInfo.country":{"$exists":false}},
        {"companyInfo.vatRegistrations":{"$exists":false}},
        {"entries":{"$exists":false}},
        {"entries":{"$size":0}},
        {"entries":{"$elemMatch":{"country":{"$exists":false}}}},
        {"entries":{"$elemMatch":{"invoicedAt":{"$exists":false}}}},
        {"$and":
        [
            {"companyInfo.country":{"$exists":true}},
            {"entries.0":{"$exists":true}},
            {"$where":"function() {  
                function foreign(entry) { 
                return obj.companyInfo != null && entry.country != null && obj.companyInfo.country != entry.country; 
                }  
                function vatReg(entry) { 
                var vatRegs = obj.companyInfo.vatRegistrations == null ? [] : obj.companyInfo.vatRegistrations;    
                return vatRegs.some(function(reg) {  
                return entry.country == reg.country && (
                reg.registrationDate.getTime() == ISODate(\"1970-01-01\").getTime() &&    
                reg.registrationEndDate.getTime() == ISODate(\"3000-01-01\").getTime() 
                || (
                entry.invoicedAt != null && entry.invoicedAt.getTime() >= reg.registrationDate.getTime() && 
                entry.invoicedAt.getTime() <= reg.registrationEndDate.getTime()    )  
                );
                });  
                }  
                function check(entry) { return foreign(entry) && !vatReg(entry); }  
                return obj.entries.some(check);}"
            }
        ]}
    ]}
]
}).count();
```

It is somewhat hard to follow, I know..
Notice the first 2 conditions are on 'jobExist' field and 'entityId'
if these 2 conditions are checked first (like if using this index on jobExists and entityId) than all the remaining documents has a 'registrationEndDate' field exists, so the query under the 'where' clause could work.

but if another index is chosen, for some reason its like trying to run the 'where' query before it runs the 2 conditions so it scans documents that dont have registrationEndDate field and fails with this exception:

> "exception":"reactivemongo.api.commands.LastError:
>   DatabaseException['TypeError: reg.registrationEndDate is undefined
>   :\nvatReg/<@:12:1\nvatReg@:9:1\ncheck@:22:31\n@:24:10\n' (code =
>   139)]\n"}

Comment: It would be helpful to better understand the situation if you would provide an exact sample query and the exact/error message that you are seeing. Also include the exact version of MongoDB you are using.

Comment: The data set itself is very complex, furthermore I cannot reveal it even if I wanted...
The query itself is even more complex ! But i will attach it.
I just gave here the concept that Im seeing, where one condition within the query is on a field that DONT Exist on all documents, But the other conditions should filter out those documents. So if mongo chooses to use the 'right' index, only documents with this attributes are scanned and result is returned but if another index is used, the query fails because it tries to calculate the later condition first.